# Encode and decode typed arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, audio-streaming, typed-arrays

I have audio buffer in Float32Array.

How to encode that to binary data before send via websockets and decode later on?

If I send Float32Array to my node server and then back to client, returned data isn't the same. Mostly filled by 0 as shown below.

Sent data: [image: Sent data]

Returned data: [image]

EDIT
My frontend code:

```
var params = {
        roomId: $stateParams.id,
        buffer: e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0)
    };
io.socket.post(AuthSvc.urlWithToken('chat/gotStream'), params);
```

My backend code:

```
gotStream: function(req, res){
  sails.sockets.broadcast(req.param('roomId'), 'voiceChat:newBuffer', req.param('buffer'));
  res.send(200);
}
```

Comment: Just make a Uint8Array view of the data. You'll need 4 times as many elements as the Float32Array. No idea about the issue of endian-ness.

Comment: What are you using to send to the server? Can you add that code to your question?

Comment: @enhzflep how would you implement that?

Comment: @OskarKamiński - It's been a while since I've played with typed arrays, though I found this page to be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays - it may well be that you need to have the data in an ArrayBuffer object first. You then create 2 views on that data, the Float32 one you've already got and then a Uint8 one on the same data - not sure, I forget - sorry. :)

Comment: @enhzflep Like documentation say, Float32Array contain data in buffer property which is BufferArray. So I decided send by websockets just this BufferArray and wrap in Float32 later on. But the problem is, when I send my BufferArray it has "byteLength: 16384" and when other sockets receive it has one byte more ("byteLength: 16385"). And because of that new Float32Array() doesn't want wrap it.

Comment: @OskarKamiński - so I guess your problem is with WebSockets then. You should sniff the traffic being sent using [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), so you can see what and where the extra byte is that's being inserted into your stream. Either that or google for problems with the websocket implementation of your browser/backend.